# Can I include Mootools framework into background page of Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, include, mootools

As title, I would know if can I include Mootools framework into background page of Chrome Extension?
I tried but without success.

Background page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script src="mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="mootools-core-1.4.2-full-compat.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extensione tha I made",
    "permissions":["contextMenus"],
    "background_page": "background_page.html",
    "browser_action":{ 
                        "name": "My First Extension!",
                        "default_icon": "Chrome_icon32bn.png",
                        /*"default_popup": "popup.html",*/
                        "default_title": "My First Extension!"
    },
    "icons": {
                "16": "Chrome_icon19color.png",
                "48": "Chrome_icon32color.png",
                "128": "Chrome_icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{ "js": ["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"] }]
```

}

Comment: Yes. You can do it this way. How do you know it isn't working? Are you getting errors in the dev console for `background.html`?

Comment: Just place those files into your extension directory - background page can load javascript files like usual html page.

Comment: Ok now it work well.
But I don't understand when i can use "content_scripts", cause to me not work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes but because you are in a sandbox when the extension is running you must load it differently:

Add this to the manifest

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not work.
Warning says: content_scripts[0] match is missing or invalid.

Comment: Ok, now it work, but upon the background page, if I would it work upon another page?